# Laravel Eloquent Relationship get not assigned data

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent

Her is my DB Structure
[image: DB Design]

I want to get 2 things.

1. Allocated Departments to a user
2. Departments not allocated to the user
   I have achived first one through hasMany() relationship in AllocatedDepartment Model

   ```
     public function departments(){
         return $this->hasMany(Department::class, 'id', 'department_id');
     }
   ```

I am not understanding how to get departments which are not allocated to the user.

EDITED:
I think you didn't get my question.
Let say I have user **A**  and departments **X Y Z**
**X** is assigned to **A**

Now I want to get list of departments assigned to **A**  Output =  **X**

and get list of departments assigned to **A**   Output = **Y Z**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Many-To-Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) and [Querying Relationship Absence](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence).

User model

```
public function departments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Department::class, 'allocated_departments', 'user_id', 'department_id');
}
```

Department model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'allocated_departments', 'department_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Now,

```
$departments = Department::doesntHave('users')->get();

// or

$users = User::doesntHave('departments')->get();
```

Comment: It dose not works.   Empty collection returned every time... Because every user has a department

Comment: I edit question review it.

Answer (score 0):

I have did this and it worked...

```
$departments = Department::whereDoesntHave('users', function (Builder $query) use ($user){
        $query->where('user_id', '=', $user->id);

    })->get();
```